# Google Maps Api - Directions Service not Working for some origin and destination

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am getting "NOT_FOUND" error When i try to display route for some origin and destination(for example, origin : Burjuman Shopping Centre - Bur Dubai - Dubai - United Arab Emirates, destination : Karama - Dubai - United Arab Emirates) using Direction service but the same works in maps.google.com.

Is there any specific reason why its working in maps.google.com and not in Google Maps API.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Deepak

Comment: When I tried looking that up on google.com it asked what I meant and offered a selection of two. Maybe it isn't showing because of the choice? Awkward one because there seem to be two entries for the same place.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any specific why its working in maps.google.com and not in Google Maps API.

It doesn't look like it really works in [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Burjuman+Shopping+Centre+-+Bur+Dubai+-+Dubai+-+United+Arab+Emirates&daddr=Karama+-+Dubai+-+United+Arab+Emirates&hl=en&sll=25.251863,55.30152&sspn=0.092999,0.110378&geocode=FRdQgQEdkNVLAyG2cSXNBAYtUClXe6nnakNfPjG2cSXNBAYtUA%3BFdwogQEdxNNLAynlHDm_10JfPjHdJS1wvlksyQ&mra=ls&t=m&z=15)

"Burjuman Shopping Centre - Bur Dubai - Dubai - United Arab Emirates" cannot be geocoded, Google Maps is returning a route between BurJuman Centre and Al Karama - Dubai.

If I use "Burjuman Centre" [it works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Burjuman%20Centre,%20Bur%20Dubai,%20Dubai,%20United%20Arab%20Emirates&geocode=1&addr2=Karama,+Dubai,+United+Arab+Emirates&geocode=2)

This [entry in the FAQ is also relevant](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_differences)

Comment: Now am able to generate the route using the place.geometry.location of the origin and destination(I am Autocomplete to select origin and destination) but the address displayed in the origin and destination marker is some street address, not the text of origin and destination i have searched. Is there any way to display the text used for searching instead of the street address.

Comment: Of course there is a way, it might not be easy or simple. What does your code currently look like?  You might have to suppress the automatically generated text and recreate yourself (or find it and change it, not sure how easy that will be).